# Assign individual tasks to SharePoint group members using "Start Approval Process"

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval

In SP Online, I have created a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow type. I'm using "Start Approval Process" to create approval tasks.

I have a SP group which has 6 users and I want to assign individual tasks to these 6 users when a workflow is initiated.But when I add this SP group to the Participants section and initiate the workflow, only 1 task is getting created.

How to make the workflow assign tasks to every users in the SP group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the `ExpandGroups` to **yes** in your `Action` Properties

**Steps**

- Right-click on your action > Select Properties.

[image]

- At  `ExpandGroups` set it to Yes

[image]

Each member of the group should now receive an independent task.

Answer (score 2):

Do as Mohamed said, set the ExpandGroups to yes in your Action Properties, then choose Parallel(all at once):

[image]